# Trigger to count the sum of the values on the contact fields and populate it on the account fields

Tags: trigger

//////////// Handler Class

```
public class Rollup_countContact {

    public static void after_insert(List<Contact> lst){
        Map<id,Account> accmap = rollup_operation(lst); 
        Acctupdate(accmap);
    }

    public static void after_update(List<Contact> lst){
        Map<id,Account> accmap = rollup_operation(lst); 
        Acctupdate(accmap);
    }

    Public static void after_delete(List<Contact> lst){
        Map<id,Account> accmap = rollup_operation(lst); 
        Acctupdate(accmap);
    }

    public static Map<Id,Account> rollup_operation(List<Contact> lst){
        Account ac = new Account();
        ac.Score1_c__c=0;
        ac.Score2_c__c=0;

        Map<id,Account> accmap=new Map<id,account>();
        for(Contact con:lst){

            ac.id=con.accountid;
            accmap.put(con.accountid,ac);
        }
        system.debug(accmap +'abaaaa');
        List<Account> Accn=new List<Account>();
        List<Contact> con=[select id,Score1_c__c,Score2_c__c,accountid from contact where accountid in:accmap.keyset()];

        for(Contact c1:con){
            if(accmap.containsKey(c1.accountid))
            { 
                ac = accmap.get(c1.accountid);
            }

            ac.id=c1.accountid;

            system.debug(ac.Score1_c__c +'aaaa');

            ac.Score1_c__c += (c1.Score1_c__c == null ? 0 : c1.Score1_c__c);
            ac.Score2_c__c += (c1.Score2_c__c == null ? 0 : c1.Score2_c__c);

            accmap.put(c1.accountid,ac);
            system.debug(accmap +'new map');
        } 
        return accmap;
    }

    public static void Acctupdate(Map<Id, account> accmap){
        system.debug(accmap.size() +'sizesssssssss');
        system.debug(accmap +'mapppppppp');
        if(accmap.size()>0)
        {
            update accmap.values();
        }
    }
}
```

//////// Trigger
This is my trigger and it is working properly but problem in updating the values on the account when we change the parent object account

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think the problem here is that you are using the same instance of an Account object for each step of your loop. This means that what you are actually doing is updating the same object as you previously updated, rather than creating a new one.

So by the end of your loop you have an accmap that looks like this

```
{
    'ID-1': Account(Id='ID-4'),
    'ID-2': Account(Id='ID-4'),
    'ID-3': Account(Id='ID-4'),
    'ID-4': Account(Id='ID-4')
}
```

What you need to do is create a completely new account object in each iteration of the loop.

This code sample shows what I mean - you can run it in execute anonymous apex - it doesn't actually save anything:

```
Account ac = new Account();
Map<String, Account> nameAccountMapSharedObject = new Map<String, Account>();

// Build a bunch of accounts into a map using the SAME account object
for (Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ac.Name = 'My account number ' + i;
    nameAccountMapSharedObject.put(ac.Name, ac);
}

// Print out the broken list of accounts
System.debug('This list was built sharing the same account object');
for (String acctName : nameAccountMapSharedObject.keySet()) {
    System.debug('Key: ' + acctName + ' Value: ' + nameAccountMapSharedObject.get(acctName));
}

// Now do it with a new object instance each iteration
Map<String, Account> nameAccountMapNewObject = new Map<String, Account>();

// Build a bunch of accounts into a map using the SAME account object
for (Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Account newAcc = new Account();
    newAcc.Name = 'My account number ' + i;
    nameAccountMapNewObject.put(newAcc.Name, newAcc);
}

// Print out the working list of accounts
System.debug('This list was built creating a new account object each iteration');
for (String acctName : nameAccountMapNewObject.keySet()) {
    System.debug('Key: ' + acctName + ' Value: ' + nameAccountMapNewObject.get(acctName));
}
```

For you, this means that your rollup function needs to look something a bit more like:

```
public static Map<Id, Account> rollup_operation(List<Contact> lst){

    Map<Id, Account> accmap = new Map<Id, Account>();

    for (Contact con : lst) {
        Account ac = new Account();
        ac.Score1_c__c = 0;
        ac.Score2_c__c = 0;
        ac.Id = con.accountId;
        accmap.put(con.accountId, ac);
    }

    System.debug(accmap +'abaaaa');

    List<Contact> con = [
        SELECT Id, Score1_c__c, Score2_c__c, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :accmap.keyset()
    ];

    for (Contact c1 : con) {
        Account ac = accmap.get(c1.accountId);

        if(ac == null) { 
            // the key doesn't exist, continue to the next item
            continue;
        }

        System.debug(ac.Score1_c__c +'aaaa');
        ac.Score1_c__c += (c1.Score1_c__c == null ? 0 : c1.Score1_c__c);
        ac.Score2_c__c += (c1.Score2_c__c == null ? 0 : c1.Score2_c__c);

        // Don't need to put the updated ac back as it's updated in place
        //accmap.put(c1.accountid,ac);
        system.debug(accmap +'new map');
    }
    return accmap;
}
```